# How to set WinMerge default zoom level?

Tags: winmerge

In WinMerge, it's possible to adjust the zoom level - but restarting WinMerge resets the zoom back default.

Is it possible to change the default zoom level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Is it possible to change the default zoom level?

No. There is an open request for this (from 2008, so I don't think there will be any action soon):

> [image]

...

> [image]

Source [#1023 Add Zoom ability to command line options](http://sourceforge.net/p/winmerge/feature-requests/1023/)